# Android: cannot start activity with ListPreference in Layout

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference

I have the following activity:

```
public class PreferenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content)==null) {
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, new Display())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public static class Display extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

}
```

**Preferences.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- A 'parent' preference, which enables/disables child preferences (below)
         when checked/unchecked. -->
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="preferences_app_enabled"
        android:summary="Select your favourite"
        android:title="@string/app_enabled"/>

    <!--
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:key="preferences_translation_type"
        android:summary="Select your favourite"
        android:title="@string/translation_type"
        android:entries="@array/translation_type_items"/>
     -->

</PreferenceScreen>
```

When i uncommented the ListPreference part of the XML app is crashing on start (PreferenceActivity is a launcher) with the following exception:

```
*PreferenceActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructo*
```

**Array values are following:**

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="translation_type_items">
        <item>floating_window</item>
        <item>notification</item>
        <item>toast_message</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="translation_type_values">
        <item>@string/floating_window</item>
        <item>@string/notification</item>
        <item>@string/toast_message</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**Full stack trace**

```
 10-05 08:31:33.064 31472-31472/domainName.com.bubbletranslate E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: domainName.com.bubbletranslate, PID: 31472
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{domainName.com.bubbletranslate/domainName.com.bubbletranslate.activity.PreferenceActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3738)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:285)
    at domainName.com.bubbletranslate.activity.PreferenceActivity$Display.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1848)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:902)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityDonut.onCreate(BaseFragmentActivityDonut.java:41)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:315)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
    at domainName.com.bubbletranslate.activity.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3738) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383)
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417) 
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428) 
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481) 
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326) 
    at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263) 
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272) 
    at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:285) 
    at domainName.com.bubbletranslate.activity.PreferenceActivity$Display.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:31) 
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044) 
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1848) 
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:902) 
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityDonut.onCreate(BaseFragmentActivityDonut.java:41) 
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:315) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85) 
    at domainName.com.bubbletranslate.activity.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:17) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3738) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:215)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getTextArray(Resources.java:448)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getTextArray(TypedArray.java:629)
    at android.preference.ListPreference.<init>(ListPreference.java:51)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383) 
at android.preference.GenericInflater.onCreateItem(GenericInflater.java:417) 
at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:428) 
at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481) 
at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326) 
at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263) 
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272) 
at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:285) 
at domainName.com.bubbletranslate.activity.PreferenceActivity$Display.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:31) 
at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678) 
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859) 
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062) 
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044) 
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1848) 
at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:902) 
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityDonut.onCreate(BaseFragmentActivityDonut.java:41) 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:315) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85) 
at domainName.com.bubbletranslate.activity.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:17) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3738) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1202) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is causing this problem please? How can I solve it in the right way please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace. Note that your last code listing shows two string arrays; you are only using one and do not have `android:entryValues`.

Answer (score 0):

Add [an `android:entryValues` attribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#attr_android:entryValues) to your `ListPreference`.

Comment: I added android:entryValues="@array/translation_type_values" Unfortunately Same result..

Comment: @redrom: Well, the original crash is stemming from `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceTextArray(AssetManager.java:215)`. So, with your original code, it was crashing trying to read `android:entries` or `android:entryValues`. You might check the stack trace from your modified code and see if you are getting the same `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the string-array to simple array value, like this:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="translation_type_items">
        <item>floating_window</item>
        <item>notification</item>
        <item>toast_message</item>
    </string-array>
    <array name="translation_type_values">
        <item>@string/floating_window</item>
        <item>@string/notification</item>
        <item>@string/toast_message</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

For value:

```
android:entries="@array/translation_type_values"
```